# Does it make sense to take the standard deviation of a uniform distribution of values?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, gaussian

You can get the mean and standard deviation of any set of numbers and come up with a Gaussian fitting them.

What does it mean if you do this with another distribution, such as a uniform distribution?

For instance, if i generate 1,000,000 uniform random numbers from 0 to 100, i get a mean of about 50 and a standard deviation of about 28.8.

Gaussians have the 68-95-99.7 rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) which say that 68% of the values are going to be +/- 1 standard deviation from the mean.

Using that logic, that says that 68% of the values in the uniform distribution are going to be between 50-28.8 and 50+28.8 aka between 21.2 and 78.8.  those values have a range of 57.6 which is definitely not accurate for a uniform distribution.  68% of the samples should be +/-34 from the mean of 50.

When i plot the normalized histogram (pdf) of these two distributions, this is what I get.

[image: Histograms of a uniform distribution (blue) and the gaussian distribution that fit it (orange))]

So, does taking the standard deviation of a uniform distribution make sense?  Can it tell me anything in particular other than a very general sense of how much dispersion the values have?  It doesn't feel very useful when the standard deviation itself has to be interpreted differently based on what sort of distribution the data itself has.  This doesn't seem to let you compare two pieces of data that may have different distributions.

Am i missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Standard Deviation has a meaning for any probability distribution, including uniform distributions.  Even for discrete distributions.  You should have no difficulty computing the standard deviation of the uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: I definitely can, and do, but what does it tell me?

Comment: Variance is the average of the squared distance from the mean, so it is a measure of dispersion. You could take, say, the average of absolute values of the distance to the mean, but that is a lot harder to work with analytically.  Still, sometimes it is a better measure. It depends on what you want to do with your data.

Comment: The part that gets me is that if the exact amount of disperaion for a std deviation value depends on the distribution of the data, then reporting mean and standard deviation seems pretty useless in the general sense. If you have 2 data sets with unknown distribution and know their mean and std dev, you still can't really compare them.

Comment: I'm not seeing your point.  Yes, knowing the mean and variance does not determine the distribution.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: To be clear:  mean and variance are useful even if they don't tell you everything.  There are, for instance, theorems like [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) which hold for all distributions.

Comment: In general, though, if you are given a data set and you know nothing at all about what it represents, then mean and variance give you some sort of feel for it, but this information falls far short of classifying the data into some familiar form.

Comment: I think I understand my confusion now (ha!). So, variance, and thus std dev are fixed things describing dispersion.  Various distributions have an expected amount of built in dispersion by nature of their shape.

Comment: Yes.  If you know the nature of the distribution then mean and variance can be used to pin it down.  But if you are ignorant of the nature of the underlying distribution, you can still use the mean and variance to answer some relevant questions.

Comment: Thanks, id accept this as an answer if you want thr points!

Comment: No need, but thanks.  Good luck!

Comment: @AlanWolfe Thats why, say, in Russia the variance is called 'dispersion' and is then denoted as $\text{D}(X)$, not $\text{Var}(X)$.